# Calendar days since date in days

Tags: postgresql, datetime

Given the following sqlfiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/f483a/2/0

```
create table test (
    start_date date
);
insert into test values ('2019/01/01');


select 
start_date, 
age(now()::date,start_date) as date_diff
from test;
```

Which generates the following output:

`date_diff | 0 years 7 mons 27 days 0 hours 0 mins 0.00 secs`

How could I instead generate the correct number of calendar days 
`239 days`
*without using a custom function*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the age function. [Subtracting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html) a `date` from a `date` yields an integer. `now()` returns a `timestamp` so you need to use `current_date` instead.

```
select start_date, 
       current_date - start_date as date_diff
from test;
```